# Getting access to non-public files from Laravel 8 storage folder with JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, three.js, laravel-8, laravel-storage

I'm in the following scenario:

- **Laravel 8** app.
- Storing by the user uploaded STL files in the `storage/app/users/{userid}` folder.
- STLs are private and may not be located in public folder and thus may not be accessible for everyone.

**Now I'm trying to get access to these private STL files through javascript to load them in my Three.js scene for viewing.**

My problem is: If I try to get the filepath from the database beforehand by using the `storage_path()` function in my Laravel controller and then pass this filepath (e.g. locally: `/Users/Leon/MyLaravelApp/storage/app/users/1/file.stl`) into my Three.js STLLoader function:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { STLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';

// {...}
let THREE_loader = new STLLoader();
let THREE_geometry;

THREE_loader.load(filePath, function (geometry) {
    THREE_geometry = geometry;

    // {...}
});
```

I - of course - get the error message 404 every time I try it, because the given path is relative to my web root and therefore not correct!

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of
> 404 (Not Found)
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/Leon/MyLaravelApp/storage/app/users/1/file.stl

Now my question is:

Is there any possible way to get around this problem? How can i access private files (not in the public folder) from javascript in my Laravel 8 app? There has to be a solution to this right?

---

Other solutions I thought about:

- Storing the files directly in the database **-> files too large?!**
- Storing an "safe" encrypted filepath of the file inside the public(!) folder in the database **-> not safe enough?!**

But both of these "solutions" are definitely not one of my favorites!

---

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Best regards, Leon

Comment: You should store the path in database and access file via that path and if folder is private you have to give read access to read file.

Comment: But if i give read access to a private file, isn't it public then?
If not, how do I do that?

Comment: If you give access to them they should be accessible. make sure you access right path

Comment: ls -l command to see folder permission

Comment: I Think my problem is that JS can't get out of the root folder because it always try to append the path to the current location as relative path and if I use ../ of course it cannot work because it's out of the public folder...

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The solution I came up with over time:

---

## Generally:

To get access to private files I figured that you must have some kind of special **web route** for that with some kind of **FileController** at the end which checks if you have **permission to view** the file and then decides to **either abort()** or **otherwise return the file itself** with a FileResponse.

---

## Laravel (my case):

#### JS

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { STLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';

let THREE_loader = new STLLoader();
let THREE_geometry;

THREE_loader.load('data/users/1/filename.stl', function (geometry) {
  THREE_geometry = geometry;

  // {...}
});
```

#### PHP (web route)

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\File\FileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('data/users/{user_id}/{filename}', [FileController::class, 'load_user_stl']);
```

#### PHP (FileController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\File;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function load_user_stl($user_id, $filename): \Illuminate\Http\Response
    {
        if (str_contains($filename, '.stl')) {
            if (Gate::allows('access-user-stl') || Auth::id() == $user_id) {
                return $this->return_user_stl($user_id, $filename);
            } else {
                abort(403);
            }
        } else {
            abort(400);
        }
    }

    public function return_user_stl($user_id, $filename): \Illuminate\Http\Response
    {
        $path = storage_path('app/data/users/'.$user_id.'/'.$filename);

        try {
            $file = File::get($path);
            $type = File::mimeType($path);
            $response = Response::make($file);
            $response->header('Content-Type', $type);

            return $response;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Hope I could help you somehow and if somebody has an even cleaner way let me know:)**

Leon